# How can I choose which frame I pick from camera texture using the delay frame patch (or any other)?

Tags: delay, frame, freeze, snapshot, spark-ar-studio

I am building an effect which needs to "freeze" the camera texture for a few seconds on certain occasions, triggered by a pulse (Just like a "snapshot" effect where you trigger it and then the image doesn't move anymore for a few seconds - If you remember Pokemon snap on N64)

I am currently trying to build it using the Delay Frame patch. I render the scene using a scene render pass, then it goes through the delay frame in the first frame input, but the problem is I don't want to freeze the first frame I want to freeze a random phrase a T= X seconds, triggered by a user defined pulse.

Do you have any insight on how I should achieve that?

Thanks a lot, have a great day !

Answer (score 0):

so what you can do is using the "Runtime patch " you can get how much time has passed since the effect has started so with that and a "greater then patch " you can make a trigger with the "pulse patch " to make the freeze.